# Post custom text with facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i am having some tweets like things and i would like to post that custom text with facebook like button. is it possible if yes then how.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add OpenGraph meta tags to the page located on URL you linking your like button. Once user click on Like Button Facebook crawl that page and post content of OG tags to feed.

Read more on [Like Button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 6):

Use  [Open Graph Tags:](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Put this tags on your page head section:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="custom image path" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="name of the website" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="custom title" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="url of the page" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="custom description" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website/article/game etc.." /> 
</head>
```

use [Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check your custom properties has affected.

[More about Opengraph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is true as both the other commenters say you would need to create a facebook app which then would require a secure canvas URL in the end to be verified. Hence the obstacle is quite high.